# Spring RestTemplate with HttpClient Client Certificate

Tags: java, spring, keystore, client-certificates, apache-httpclient-5.x

How can I include client certificate using latest HttpClient (httpclient5)?

I'm using hakky54 sslcontext with latest RestTemplate (rest framework 6.0.4) and HttpClient.  It throws exception when I create an in-mem keystore (same result with "PKCS12" and "JKS") with just my certificate

> 500 Internal Server Error: "{"ErrorCode":"APPAP330E","ErrorMsg":"Failed to verify application authentication data: Could not obtain client certificate details."}"

Syntax in Kotlin:

```
val x509 : X509Certificate = getCertificateFromStore(...)
val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
val request = HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()
val httpClient : HttpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()

val clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
val clientManager = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
clientStore.load(null)
clientStore.setCertificateEntry("clientCert", x509 )
clientManager.init(clientStore, null)

val sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
        .withIdentityMaterial(clientManager)
        .build()
val connectionManager : HttpClientConnectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(Apache5SslUtils.toSocketFactory(sslFactory))
        .build()
httpClient.setConnectionManager(connectionManager)

request.httpClient = httpClient.build()
restTemplate.requestFactory = request
...
val response : ResponseEntity<String> = restTemplate.getForEntity(...)
```

In Windows if I replace keystore init with `val clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY")` with just one client cert in the store it works fine

I need the ability to pick a different cert that's in the store or use a cert that's not pre-installed

Am I not configuring the keystore correctly?  How can I inject a client cert into a resttemplate request in the latest Spring Framework.  It seems the latest Spring Framework and httpclient5 are not compatible with all the samples I have found online that rely on httpclient4

Comment: It looks like you are creating a client manager without the key entry. You added a certificate entry to the in memory keystores which in this case only contains the certificate entry aka  as trusted certificate. The key/identity is missing. You should add a key entry with a private key and certificate chain to your in memory keystores to get it working